# dynamic text box in zend form

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, zend-form

me created a zend form and want to add dynamic text box in it.
created it using javascript.
but on submit of the form, only data in the last created text box is posted.
please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count1 = 0;
    var count2 = 0;
    var count3 = 0;
    var count4 = 0;
    var count5 = 0;
    var count6 = 0;
    $('#addone').click(function() {
        $('#link-element').append($('<input id="link" class="link" type="text" name="link"/>').hide().slideDown(100));
        count1++;
    });
    $('#addtwo').click(function() {
        $('#youtube-element').append($('<input id="yahoo'+count2+'" class="link" type="text" name="yahoo"/>').hide().slideDown(100));
        count2++;
    });
    $('#addthree').click(function() {
        $('#gamepuzzle-element').append($('<input id="gamepuzzle'+count3+'" class="link" type="text" name="gamepuzzle"/>').hide().slideDown(100));
        count3++;
    });
    $('#addfour').click(function() {
        $('#flashgame-element').append($('<input id="flashgame'+count4+'" class="link" type="text" name="flashgame"/>').hide().slideDown(100));
        count4++;
    });
    $('#addfive').click(function() {
        $('#moketest-element').append($('<input id="moketest'+count5+'" class="link" type="text" name="moketest"/>').hide().slideDown(100));
        count5++;
    });
    $('#addsix').click(function() {
        $('#indigenousintegration-element').append($('<input id="indigenousintegration'+count6+'" class="link" type="text" name="indigenousintegration"/>').hide().slideDown(100));
        count6++;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send the form inputs as an array.
E.g.

```
$('#addsix').click(function() {
    $('#indigenousintegration-element').append($('<input id="indigenousintegration'+count6+'" class="link" type="text" name="indigenousintegration[]"/>').hide().slideDown(100));
    count6++;
});
```

Notice the [] at the end of the name of the input.

Comment: thanku so much.
this worked for me.
since the 'name' in my code is same in the form also it overwritten the form default input when done as u said.
now me renamed this dynamic field as name="indigenousintegrationmore[]".
it worked.
thanku so much..